# Error with Node.js API for GPT3.5 on AWS Lambda: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'completions')"

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, openai-api, gpt-3

I'm attempted to allow myself to text GPT3.5 and cannot figure out why I keep getting carious errors for this line.

When I use openai.chat.completions.create, as the latest documentation suggests,I get the following error:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'completions')`

If I use the prior format of invoking completions with openai.createCompletion, I get the following error instead:

`TypeError: openai.createChatCompletion is not a function`

I've read every piece of documentation I can, and tried even older ways of invoking completions, but cannot get anything to work.

I've already tried getting a new API key and doing npm update, and still get the same issue. Here's my full code, I must be missing something:

```
const openai = require('openai');

const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;

const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

openai.apiKey = process.env.OPENAI_AUTH,

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const buff = Buffer.from(event.body, "base64");
    const formEncodedParams = buff.toString("utf-8");
    const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(formEncodedParams);

    const body = urlSearchParams.get("Body");
    const from = urlSearchParams.get("From");

    const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      engine: "gpt-3.5-turbo", // GPT-3.5 Turbo
      messages: [
        { role: "system", content: body },
      ],
      max_tokens: 100, // You can adjust this as needed
    });

    await sendMessageBack(completion.data.choices[0].message.content, from);
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify('Message sent successfully'),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify('Error sending message'),
    };
  }
};

async function sendMessageBack(msg, to) {
  try {
    await client.messages.create({
      body: msg,
      to: to,
      from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUM,
    });
    console.log('Message sent:', msg);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error sending message:', e);
  }
}
```

I have tried updating the openai package, new invocations of completions, old invocations, reading the documentation, but AWS  Lambda keeps throwing errors on that same line.

EDIT: The solutions below led to the following rewrite. Including it here in case it's helpful to anyone else:

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_AUTH, 
});

import twilio from 'twilio';

const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;

const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const buff = Buffer.from(event.body, "base64");
    const formEncodedParams = buff.toString("utf-8");
    const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(formEncodedParams);

    const msgBody = urlSearchParams.get("Body");
    const from = urlSearchParams.get("From");

    const chatCompletion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [{ role: "system", content: msgBody }],
      max_tokens: 100,
    });

    await sendMessageBack(chatCompletion.choices[0].message.content, from);
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify('Message sent successfully'),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify('Error sending message'),
    };
  }
};

async function sendMessageBack(msg, to) {
  try {
    await client.messages.create({
      body: msg,
      to: to,
      from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUM,
    });
    console.log('Message sent:', msg);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error sending message:', e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code is throwing `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'completions')` is because `openai.chat` was not even defined, so it's trying to access a variable or a property that has not been declared yet. That makes sense because usually libraries like this provide a base class to construct everything internally, like the OpenAI one. So you must instantiate it's original class first, like this:

Using `openai:4.2.0`:

```js
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: 'your api key', // defaults to process.env["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
});
```

rather than:

```js
const openai = require('openai');

openai.apiKey = process.env.OPENAI_AUTH;
```

Because the later just imports the OpenAI package, but doesn't instantiate it, so just sets the apiKey as a variable there. The package base class knows how to do it internally, and it helps them to better maintain it.

Also, I'd like to recommend changing `engine: "gpt-3.5-turbo",` to `model: "gpt-3.5-turbo"` at line 18, as `model` is the new way of specifiing it.

Comment: Appreciate this. I'll need to update my package.json file to allow this on Lambda since by default it doesn't want to handle modules.

Then I'll have to rework the Twilio lines to use an import rather than require. Hopefully that should knock this out.

Comment: Looks to be working now. Added the corrected code to the original question for anyone else that may be running into similar issues. Thanks again!